# kdb: getting one row from HDB

Tags: kdb

For a normal table, we can select one row using `select[1] from t`. How can I do this for HDB?

---

I tried `select[1] from t where date=2021.02.25` but it gives error

`Not yet implemented: it probably makes sense, but it’s not defined nor implemented, and needs more thinking about as the language evolves`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select[n]` syntax works only if table is already loaded in memory.
The easiest way to get 1st row of HDB table is:

```
1#select from t where date=2021.02.25
```

`select[n]` will work if applied on already loaded data, e.g.

```
select[1] from select from t where date=2021.02.25
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before for ad-hoc queries by using the virtual index i, which should avoid the cost of pulling all data into memory just to select a couple of rows. If your query needs to map constraints in first before pulling a subset, this is a reasonable solution.

It will however pull N rows for each date partition selected due to the way that q queries work under the covers. So YMMV and this might not be the best solution if it was behind an API for example.

```
/ 5 rows (i[5] is the 6th row)
select from t where date=2021.02.25, sum=`abcd, price=1234.5, i<i[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table is date partitioned, you can simply run

```
select col1,col2 from t where date=2021.02.25,i=0
```

That will get the first record from 2021.02.25's partition, and avoid loading every record into memory.

Per your first request (which is different to above) `select[1] from t`, you can achieve that with

```
.Q.ind[t;enlist 0]
```